# dynamic memory for 2D char array

Tags: c, memory-management

I have declared an array 
char **arr; 
How to initialize the memory for the 2D char array.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Answer (score 16):

One way is to do the following:

```
char **arr = (char**) calloc(num_elements, sizeof(char*));

for ( i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ )
{
    arr[i] = (char*) calloc(num_elements_sub, sizeof(char));
}
```

It's fairly clear what's happening here - firstly, you are initialising an array of pointers, then for each pointer in this array you are allocating an array of characters.

You could wrap this up in a function. You'll need to free() them too, after usage, like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ )
{
    free(arr[i]);
}

free(arr);
```

I think this the easiest way to do things and matches what you need.

Comment: I would use "*arr" instead of "char*" for the first calloc. And "**arr" instead of "char" for the calloc in the loop.

Comment: By doing multiple allocations, the memory will not be continuous. Will it work fine while incrementing a pointer to access the value.

Comment: @Ankur only withtin a *row* of the 2D array

Comment: @Andrei So might I, (@Ankur - this is to guarantee you don't mix up the types) but I think what I've done here is clearer for an explanation.

Answer (score 11):

There are two options for allocating an array of type `char **`

I've transcribed these 2 code samples from the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) (which also contains a nice illustration of these two array types)

*Option 1* - Do one allocation *per row* plus one for the row pointers.

```
char **array1 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(char *)); // Allocate row pointers
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
  array1[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(char));  // Allocate each row separately
```

*Option 2* - Allocate *all the elements together* and allocate the row pointers:

```
char **array2 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(char *));      // Allocate the row pointers
array2[0] = malloc(nrows * ncolumns * sizeof(char)); // Allocate all the elements
for(i = 1; i < nrows; i++)
  array2[i] = array2[0] + i * ncolumns;
```

You can also allocate only *one memory block* and use some arithmetic to get at element `[i,j]`. But then you'd use a `char*` not a `char**` and the code gets complicated. e.g. `arr[3*ncolumns + 2]` instead of `arr[3][2]`

Answer (score 4):

You might be better off with a one dimensional array:

```
char *arr = calloc(WIDTH*HEIGHT, sizeof(arr[0]));

for (int y=0; y<HEIGHT; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<WIDTH; x++)
        arr[WIDTH*y+x] = 2*arr[WIDTH*y+x];

free(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following trick:

```
typedef char char2D[1][1];

char2D  *ptr;

ptr = malloc(rows * columns, sizeof(char));

for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        (*ptr)[i][j] = char_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

By 2D char array, if you mean a matrix of strings then it may be done in the following way.

```
int nChars = 25; // assuming a max length of 25 chars per string
int nRows = 4;
int nCols = 6;
char *** arr = malloc(nRows * sizeof(char **));
int i;
int j;
for(i = 0; i < nCols; ++i)
{
    arr[i] = malloc(nCols * sizeof(char *));
}
for(i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j < nCols; ++j)
    {
        arr[i][j] = malloc(nChars * sizeof(char));
        sprintf(arr[i][j], "Row %d Col %d", i, j);
    }
}
```

To print the 2D char array(matrix of strings(char arrays))

```
for(i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j < nCols; ++j)
    {
        printf("%s  ", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Result is

```
Row 0 Col 0    Row 0 Col 1    Row 0 Col 2    Row 0 Col 3    Row 0 Col 4    Row 0 Col 5  
Row 1 Col 0    Row 1 Col 1    Row 1 Col 2    Row 1 Col 3    Row 1 Col 4    Row 1 Col 5  
Row 2 Col 0    Row 2 Col 1    Row 2 Col 2    Row 2 Col 3    Row 2 Col 4    Row 2 Col 5  
Row 3 Col 0    Row 3 Col 1    Row 3 Col 2    Row 3 Col 3    Row 3 Col 4    Row 3 Col 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char **array;
int row,column;
char temp='A';
printf("enter the row");
scanf("%d",&row);
printf("enter the column");
scanf("%d",&column);
array=(char **)malloc(row*sizeof(char *));
for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    array[i]=(char*)malloc(column*sizeof(char));
}
```