# error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
the_project.c:73:22: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

it gives the error above and the line 73 is the following.

```
customer_table[my_id][3] = worker_no;
```

I declared the array global as follows

```
int *customer_table;     //All the info about the customer
```

This line of code is in a function not in main.
And I allocate memory for this global array in the main.
What may this cause this problem?

Comment: The "nor vector" part of the error message makes me think you're compiling as C++, not as C.  If you want to compile C code, use a C compiler.

Comment: @KeithThompson i am using gcc

Comment: Interesting.  It's related to a [gcc extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring a `pointer-to-int`. So `cutomer_table[x]` is an int, not a pointer. If you need a two-dimensional, dynamically allocated array, you'll need a:

```
int **customer_table;
```

and you'll need to be very careful with the allocation.

(See e.g. [dynamic memory for 2D char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614249/dynamic-memory-for-2d-char-array) for examples.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `customer_table[my_id]` is not a pointer or array and hence you cannot use `[]` on it.

Note that the first dereference using `[]` is OK since `customer_table` is a pointer. Once you apply the first `[]` it becomes an `int`, though.

Perhaps what you really want to use is

```
int **customer_table;
```