# how to declare dynamic 2D array in C set by the number of inputs

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamic memory for 2D char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614249/dynamic-memory-for-2d-char-array)

hi i am wondering how can i declare a dynamic 2D array where the size of array is set by the number of inputs enter. Example:

```
user input:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

array[0][0] == 1    array[0][1] == 2    array[0][2] == 3
array[1][0] == 4    array[1][1] == 5    array[1][2] == 6
array[2][0] == 7    array[2][1] == 8    array[2][2] == 9
```

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth. NO, this is not a duplicate for that q. And I also whant to know an expert answer!

Comment: @qPCR4vir: What is that question/answer missing?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth the part of deducing the size of the array to be created: the info is in the input self.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`malloc()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html). Hint: you'll need pointers to pointers if you want to emulate a two-dimensional array.

Comment: I think the problems is that we need to scan the input to know the size of the array to be create... but then where to save the input temporaly?? We make an arbitrary length array and by need realloc it?

Comment: @qPCR4vir For example, yes. Or ask the user to enter the number of rows and columns.

Comment: i am trying to avoid having the user input the number of rows and columns.

Comment: @menotyou Then keep track of whenever you get valid input? Maybe utilize the return of `scanf`? Then use `realloc` to change the amount of memory you have allocated.

Comment: @menotyou Then use realloc, as qPCR4vir mentioned.

Comment: I can write a procedure for this, but I think it is a very common situation and I wanted to see a correct one, long tested by one of you, experienced C programers. I had the problem too!

Comment: pointers to pointers are not really necessary for this. a single 1d array is enough if you are able to pack the rows into one.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Of course it's not mandatory, but I assumed OP wanted the convenient `array[row][column]` syntax.

Comment: Try looking up `calloc()`and see if it suits better

Comment: @H2CO3 hm, that makes sense. I'm wondering if malloc'ing a 2d array could, depending on the malloc implementation, actually be faster than having to calculate the offset in the 1d array on each access.

Comment: It is not true that pointers to pointers are needed to emulate a two-dimensional array, and it is typically inefficient to do so. C supports variable-length arrays. Once the row length is known, the pointer may be declared with `TYPE (*p)[length]`, assigned space with malloc, and used as `p[i][j]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Did you read my comment above? Will you revoke your (**unjust**) downvote if I change "you'll need" to "you most probably intend to"?

Comment: Your comment is wrong: Assuming the OP wants `array[row][column]` syntax does not mean pointers to pointers are needed. The declaration I showed shows how to get the syntax without pointers to pointers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Tricky: you don't answer my question, instead you edit your previous comment so now it seems I'm acting dumb. Clever, indeed.

Comment: I did not edit the comment.