# Strange output while using dynamic memory allocation i C

Tags: c

I'm working on this code, and it's not finished yet. But while testing the add new contacts function and printing function, I get this strange output. Everythin looks ok as long as I'm not adding more than one contact. What am I doing wrong here?

```
//Libraries:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Function prototypes
int showMenu(); //Shows user options

//Main function
int main() {

    //Variable declerations
    int i = 0;
    int iOption = 0;
    int iContacts = 0;
    char *cPhoneBook_name;
    int *iPhoneBook_nr;

    cPhoneBook_name = (char *) calloc(1, 80 * sizeof(char));
    iPhoneBook_nr = (int *) calloc(1, sizeof(int));

    do {

        //Memory check
        if(cPhoneBook_name == NULL || iPhoneBook_nr == NULL){
            printf("\nOut of Memory!\n");
            return;
        }

        //Show menu
        iOption = showMenu();

        switch (iOption) {
            case 1: //Add contact
                printf("\nEnter name:\n");
                scanf("%s", &cPhoneBook_name[iContacts]);
                printf("\nEnter number:\n");
                scanf("%d", &iPhoneBook_nr[iContacts]);
                cPhoneBook_name = realloc(cPhoneBook_name, 80 * sizeof(char));
                iPhoneBook_nr = realloc(iPhoneBook_nr, sizeof(int));
                iContacts += 1;
                break;
            case 2: //Modify contact
                //Code here
                break;
            case 3: //Show contacts
                for(i = 0 ; i < iContacts ; i++) {
                    printf("\n%s %d\n", &cPhoneBook_name[i], iPhoneBook_nr[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 4: //Free memory (delete contacts)
                free(cPhoneBook_name);
                free(iPhoneBook_nr);
                break;
        }
    }while(iOption != 5);//Exit if iOption is 5;

    system("clear");
    return 0;
}


//Function definition - showMenu()
int showMenu() {

    int iOption = 0;

    //system("clear");

    printf("\n   Phone book   \n");
    printf("------------------------\n");
    printf("1. Add new contact.\n");
    printf("2. Edit existing contact\n");
    printf("3. Show contact(s)\n");
    printf("4. Clear phone book\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");
    printf("------------------------\n");
    printf("Option --> ");
    scanf("%d", &iOption);

    return iOption;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Show us an example of this "strange output", otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Why are you allocating memory and not putting anything into it?

Comment: You should also do the freeing before the program exits.

Comment: Your main problem is that your scanf's are going into unallocated memory.

Comment: Take a look here: [dynamic memory for 2D char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614249/dynamic-memory-for-2d-char-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within this:

```
printf("\n%s %d\n", &cPhoneBook_name[i], iPhoneBook_nr[i]);
```

`cPhoneBook_name` if of type `char[]`. So for example the expression `char[1]` gives you the second charachter in the list. While a name in your code is 80 `char`s wide. So try:

```
printf("\n%s %d\n", &cPhoneBook_name[i*80], iPhoneBook_nr[i]);
```

## Edit:

I also found that this:

```
cPhoneBook_name = realloc(cPhoneBook_name, 80 * sizeof(char));
```

Has no effect, because you're resizing `cPhoneBook_name` from 80 to 80.
try:

```
    cPhoneBook_name = realloc(cPhoneBook_name, (iContacts+1) 80 * sizeof(char));
```

and also:
     scanf("%s", &cPhoneBook_name[80*iContacts]);

Comment: This line is also having no effect. `iPhoneBook_nr = realloc(iPhoneBook_nr, sizeof(int));` and failing to extend the array of numbers.

Comment: Good find :). So in general just remember `pointer = realloc(pointer*newItemCount*sizeof(type))`.

Comment: Ahem, `pointer = realloc(pointer , newItemCount*sizeof(type))`.

Comment: Haha, oops, i'll go make coffee ;)

Comment: Thanks @Davidvanrijn ! It helped a lot! I finished the code with your help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely the root of your "strange ouput" when you enter more than one contact:

```
cPhoneBook_name = realloc(cPhoneBook_name, 80 * sizeof(char));
```

You're not actually extending the size of the `cPhoneBook_name` array; in a `realloc` call, the second parameter is the *new size* of the array, not the amount to add to the existing size.

Having said that, this whole approach is wrong; you're not creating an array of strings, you're (unsuccessfully) creating a single string that gets extended every time you add a contact, and your `iContacts` index will point to the `i`'th *character* of the string, not the `i`'th string in the list of strings.

Here's an approach that should work:

```
#define ROWS 5 // start with 5 rows in your contact list

// Create a type to store a single phone book entry
struct PhoneBookEntry {
  char name[80];  // fixed size to keep things simple
  int number;
};

// Create an array that can initially store ROWS
// phone book entries
struct PhoneBookEntry *phoneBook = malloc ( sizeof *phoneBook * ROWS );
size_t phoneBookRows = ROWS;
...
case 1: // Add contact
  // Before adding a contact, see if we need to extend the phone book
  // array
  if ( iContacts == phoneBookRows )
  {
    // double the size of the phone book array
    struct PhoneBookEntry *tmp = realloc( phoneBook, 2 * sizeof *phoneBook * phoneBookRows );
    if ( tmp )
    {
      phoneBook = tmp;
      phoneBookRows *= 2; 
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "Could not extend phone book!\n" );
      break;
    }
  }
  ...
  scanf( "%s", phoneBook[iContacts].name ); // note no & operator; arrays are special
  ...
  scanf( "%d", &phoneBook[iContacts].number );
```

Some things to note:

First, **DO NOT** cast the result of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` in C code; it's unnecessary, and under C89 compilers can mask a bug.  You *do* need to cast the results of those functions in C++ code, but if you're writing C++ you shouldn't be using `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` anyway.

Second, avoid using type names as `sizeof` arguments where you can help it.  Use something like the following instead:

```
T *p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `T`, so `sizeof *p` is equivalent to `sizeof (T)`.  This way, `malloc` will always allocate the correct amount of memory regardless of `T`, and if you ever decide to change `T`, you only have to make that change in one place.

Third, `realloc` will return `NULL` if it can't satisfy the request; if you assign that `NULL` to your `phoneBook` variable, you will lose your reference to the memory you've already allocated.  It's safer to assign the result of `realloc` to a temporary variable, test for `NULL`, and then assign it to your `phoneBook` variable.

Fourth, `realloc` calls can be expensive, so you want to minimize them when it makse sense to do so.  Doubling the size of the array is a common technique.